# spring batch threads not returning after execution of main thread is complete

Tags: multithreading, spring, spring-batch

I am novice to spring batch. I have created and successfully executed job from spring by using multiple threads and it works perfetly fine except that when program execution is complete, program flow does not comes to end/halt. i.e. even when the last statement of main method gets executed program does not exit. I am not sure whether it keeps on waiting for threads to complete or what. Can someone please advice on this ?
"Below is my config file for job

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
            <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
</bean>

<batch:job id="helloWorldJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
       <batch:step id="step0" next="step1">
                <batch:tasklet ref="hello" transaction-manager="transactionManager" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
       </batch:step>        
       <batch:step id="step1">
                <batch:tasklet ref="world" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
       </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

And below is the launcher code

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("simpleJob.xml");

            JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
            builder.addString("Date", "12/02/2011");
            jobLauncher.run(job, builder.toJobParameters());

            JobExecution jobExecution = jobRepository.getLastJobExecution(job.getName(), builder.toJobParameters());

            System.out.println("\n\n"+jobExecution.toString());
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("End of execution ");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

As stated above, the code runs in 5 different thread for  the task "hello" and once for task "world" though it does not bring the execution of main program to halt even after the last line of main method "End of execution" gets executed.
Any link white paper will greatly be appriciated.
Thanks in advance
Samir

Comment: I find the `Thread.sleep(5000)` in the middle there a bit suspicious.  Why would you need to do that?  Shouldn't the job execution block in the launcher.

Another comment: the return value form the job launcher is a JobExecution, so there is no need to fetch it again from the JobRepository.

Answer (score 1):

Your thread pool is not being shutdown.  Probably the best way to do that is to call close() on your application context (in a finally block to be safe).

Comment: Hello Dave,Thank you so much for looking into this. Though here my threadpool is managed by spring. I dont have handle to it. Are you suggesting to access it through factory and then close it ?

Comment: And also if I close the application context itself I will not be able to perform any additional work after the task execution is over. I want to be able to run some code in single thread once the execution of the task is complete.

Comment: I don't think there's anything stopping you from running more code is there?  Just close the context when you are done.