# ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is not closing even after closing context and job is finished

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch job with two partitioned steps. I configured separate `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` for both slave steps since I need different pool settings.

Both Master Steps - Configured `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` as `TaskExecutor`

Both Slave Steps - Configured Separate `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` as `TaskExecutor`

I am doing this to achieve parallel slave steps in addition to parallel chunks for a slave step.

Once my job is finished, I see my thread pools configured in last slave step kept hanging so job didn't terminate.

I am using Spring Boot.

I am closing context ( `ConfigurableApplicationContext`) as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699516/spring-batch-threads-not-returning-after-execution-of-main-thread-is-complete).

Doing `System.exit(0)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948102/partitioned-job-cant-stop-by-itself-after-finishing-spring-batch) solves my problem but I am wondering if there is a clean way that I can shutdown thread pools explicitly or if I have done any wrong configuration.

Please suggest.

Comment: Are you running spring-boot with web application or without web application? What is spring-boot logs says?

Comment: I guess, Its embedded tomcat but I simply call , `SpringApplication
      .run(...)` from `main(String[] args)`. Logs doesn't say anything specific, job completes and remains live because those thread pools remain live. I don't see any attempt in logs to close down those pools. Once call `SpringApplication
      .run(..)` completes , I do , `ctx.close()`.

Comment: We've seen a fair amount of odd behavior from `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` as well, especially with error handling. Assuming you're not using an huge number of threads, I'd just use `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` everywhere and allow garbage collection to take care of the spent threads.

Comment: in fact `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` is not even closing after completing a slave step. I can see in profiler that all `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` remain live after completing a slave step when no task executor is specified in slaves and master step has `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`.  So there are issues even if there is only `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`.

Comment: Same issue. SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor is hanging with connection even after task completion